# How to display the git branch in the conda terminal prompt on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, conda, prompt

The conda powershell terminal prompt shows the current active environment. I also want to see the git branch if the prompt is in a git repo. How do i do this?
I saw many solutions online for Windows PowerShell prompt, but those don't work for the conda powershell prompt.

Comment: What is `conda powershell terminal prompt`? By default the `anaconda prompt` uses `cmd.exe`. Did you get it to use powershell somehow?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Anaconda also offers an Anaconda Powershell Prompt, which opens the anaconda prompt in powershell.